# What does "Marchentalender" on the front of a postcard mean?

Tags: meaning

I have a 1950s (I think) postcard of a girl surrounded by flowers with "Marchentalender" written below. Does anyone know what it means?

Also, I have a postcard with the description Das ubertreteneVerbot. Can anyone help with translations?

Comment: *You* have, we don't. Please provide a picture.

Comment: Ist es vielleicht "Das übertretene Verbot"? Mir liegen die Postkarten nicht vor, aber Zusammenschreibungen mit Camelcase sind im Deutschen grundsätzlich falsch, außer in Abkürzungen (GmbH, BaFöG) und "ubertretene" kein Wort. Ähnlich mag es im ersten Fall "Märchental" heißen. Bitte kontrollieren und ersetzen.

Answer (score 38):

It would help to see a picture to confirm.

However, I am pretty sure the first card says "Märchenkalender" (fairy tale calendar) - and you

1. missed to type the diacritics in Märchen (please note that these are not just decorations in German; hence, if your keyboard is lacking the umlauts ä, ö  or ü, you should type ae, oe or ue instead)
2. misread an *k* for a *t*, which can happen in some fonts (please read [this Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur_(Schrift)#Schreib-_und_Lesehilfe) section for an example)

---

Your second example lacks the diacritics as well. It should be "Das übertretene Verbot" - and it seems to be the German title of a Finnish fairy tale. You can find a German version [here](http://www.zeno.org/M%C3%A4rchen/M/Finnland/August+von+L%C3%B6wis+of+Menar%3A+Finnische+und+estnische+M%C3%A4rchen/30.+Das+%C3%BCbertretene+Verbot).

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @DorothyJStrickland If the answer has helped you, please upvote and accept it as outlined in the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) so that others will know this question need no further answers.

Comment: +1 for solving by the somewhat flawed description alone!

Answer (score 13):

The word *Marchentalender* does not exist. However, from the context one can infer that the word is probably **Märchenkalender**.

The word *Märchenkalender* is a composition of *Märchen*, meaning *fairy tale*, and *Kalender*, meaning *calendar*. Therefore, a *Märchenkalender* is a **fairy tale calendar**.

The words *das übertretene Verbot* may be translated as *the violated ban*.

Comment: Many thanks. Most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's far-fetched, but it **could** actually be Marchentalender (and not a misreading of Märchenkalender). Actually *seeing* a picture of that photograph would help...

What could Marchentalender mean if that is truly what's written there?

Marchental is a location near Wilder Kaiser (a mountain) in Austria. Prepending a first name, and sometimes a last name with either a profession or location to distinguish between people is not at all uncommon in the south.
Such as *der Eisenbahn-Müller*, or *der Kugler-Sepp*, or *der Marchental-Alois*. Or, well, why not... der Marchental-Ender (im Gegensatz zum Speichersee-Ender).

It so happens that Ender is a not too uncommon last name in Austria and even a (albeit very rare) first name. So... that would generally be possible. Something that orginates from that particular Ender (a drawing?) might be called or labeled Marchentalender.

Answer (score 1):

Another less probable interpretation could be that it means "Märchental Ender", meaning "Fairy tale vally Ender". While I can find locations that describe themselves as Märchental I can not find anything for Ender.

The "Märchenkalender" is more probable I think, meaning "Fairy tale calendar", but we can not be sure without a picture.

The second phrase is correctly spelled "das übertretene Verbot". Which can be translated to "the transgressed ban/prohibition"

Answer (score 0):

`Das übertretene Verbot` means `the violated prohibition` (there are a few verbs which would reflect the same meaning); but it's little a difficult to find the best-matching verb by the title only... while I'd suspect the meaning to be compliance propaganda of whatever kind, probably in form of a `Groschenroman`.

And concerning that strange word, which isn't understandable German... a picture would help much, since some people can still read Old-German (you might have misread that) - I would bet it reads `Mädchenkalender`; something alike the `Bayerischer Jungbauernkalender "Girls Edition"`, where the main key-words are `girls` and `calendar`.

`Märchen` and `Mädchen` have a whole different meaning ...the front-page should tell which one it is.